# How to identify a component is spark or mx

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I need to check the component is spark or mx I have tried with checking `is IVisualElementContainer`
But both spark and mx component are fall into `IVisualElementContainer` my code sample are as follows

```
displayMessage(vidbox, 'videbox removed');

public function displayMessage(messageParent:*, message:String, fontSize:String = "30"):void {
   messageLabel.text = message; 
   if(messageParent is IVisualElementContainer)         
        messageParent.addElement(messageLabel);
   else
    messageParent.addChild(messageLabel);
}
```

any helps are highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [getQualifiedClassName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29) which returns "the fully qualified class name of an object.", so then you can check if class name starts with "mx." or "spark.".

Code sample:

```
var fullClassName:String = getQualifiedClassName(messageParent).toLowerCase();

if(fullClassName.indexOf("spark.") == 0)
{
    //spark comp
    messageParent.addElement(messageLabel);
}
else if(fullClassName.indexOf("mx.") == 0)
{
    // mx comp
    messageParent.addChild(messageLabel);
}
else
{
    // other
}
```

Comment: What is messageLabel in your case? Spark Label? TextInput?